# Using multi-line formatted text in wiki syntax

Tags: mediawiki, formatting

Using multi-line formatted text (using the `<pre>` tags) inside of a list in Mediawiki is giving me problems.

What I would love to do is something like this:

```
# Text in a numbered entry
#:<pre>Formated
Text
Goes
Here</pre>
# Next numbered entry
```

However, this will only place the first line of text in the list, and will not format the rest of the text.

If I leave the `#:` out, then the list will restart (at 1) for the next entry:

```
# Number 1 in list
<pre>Formated
Text
Goes
Here</pre>
# Also 1 in list
```

This question is [discussed](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help_talk%3aWikitext_examples#Pre-nowiki_inside_list_example_doesn.27t_seem_to_work) on [Wiki's meta](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help_talk%3aWikitext_examples), but I have been unable to find an acceptable solution to my problem.

Does anyone have a work around or something for my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use standard HTML syntax (which is totally valid wiki-syntax):

```
<ol>
<li> Text in a numbered entry</li>
<li><pre>Formated
Text
Goes
Here</pre></li>
<li> Next numbered entry</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  The only thing is that I wish I could mix the HTML and Wikitext for the list, but at least it works!

Comment: @Klee1: You can use all other wikitext (like bolding) in the list but not the list-specific wikitext (unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

I added an answer over on StackOverflow on a similar question that people might find interesting.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8390173/490487